# Understanding how two sets are equal

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand this formal statement,

$$\forall A \, \forall B \, ( \forall X \, (X \in A \iff X \in B) \implies A = B)$$

What do the universal quantifiers $$\forall A \forall B$$ indicate? Do they mean that we are talking about all of the elements in the sets A and B? And thus, that the two sets are equal?

Comment: No: they mean that this is a statement about all possible pairs of sets $A$ and $B$. ‘For each set $A$ and each set $B$ it is the case that if $A$ and $B$ have the same elements, then $A=B$.’

Comment: OK, so this statement is different than A=B⇔∀x((x∈A)↔(x∈B))?

Comment: Technically that statement is about some specific sets $A$ and $B$; the one in your question says that that statement is true of **all** sets $A$ and $B$. Note, though, that the version without the quantifiers is sometimes intended to be understood as having $\forall A\forall B$ in front of it: when that can reasonably be understood from context they are sometimes omitted in the interests of readability.

Comment: Also, by standard rules of indference, both $\phi\vdash \forall a\,\phi$ and $\forall a\,\phi\vdash \phi$ (with mild conditions on $a$)

Comment: "Note, though, that the version without the quantifiers is sometimes intended to be understood as having ∀A∀B in front of it." I was wondering that, so thank you for clarifying. So, the two statements are similar, yes? Could you describe how they are different again?

Comment: @watchy The statement you wrote doesn't include an **introduction** of the terms $A$ and $B$: are they specific sets we've already defined? Are we intended to *universally quantify* over them (this is what you intend)? What you've written has an implicit universal quantifier, and much of the time it's fine to leave these out, but if we're being fully rigorous we should generally include them explicitly.

Comment: So, if I were to introduce sets A and B to the statement A=B⇔∀x((x∈A)↔(x∈B)), then this statement would be the same as the one in my original post, correct?

Comment: With the only difference being the bidirectional equivalent, yes?

Comment: Is it assumed that the sets A and B are empty from the start and that the elements X (or x) are the only elements in each set of A and B?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the quantifiers is that in order for *any* two sets to be defined as equal to one another, the statement ($X \in A \Leftrightarrow X \in B$) must hold.

Comment: Is it assumed that the sets A and B are empty from the start and that the elements X (or x) are the only elements in each set of A and B?

Comment: @watchy  If both sets are empty, the statement still holds.  $p \leftrightarrow q$ is true when p and q are both true, and true when both p and q are both false.  So if A and B are empty, then $\forall x(x\in A \leftrightarrow x\in B) is true, because there is no x in A and x in B.